# Making a marquee in jQuery, but the animation stutters when the loop reaches the end, and starts over?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build a 100% width marquee, with infinite loop going right to left, with only one element. But calculate how many elements it will take to fill out the container. There must be no gap between the end off the loop and the text start.
But there's some stutter in the animation, when the loop has to start over. How can I avoid this stutter?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function calculateElements() {
    const containerWidth = $('.marquee-container').width();
    const elementWidth = $('.marquee-content span').outerWidth(true);
    const numElements = Math.ceil(containerWidth / elementWidth) + 3;

    for (let i = 1; i < numElements; i++) {
      $('.marquee-content').append($('.marquee-content span:first').clone());
    }
  }

  calculateElements();
});
```

```css
.marquee-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}

.marquee-content {
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  animation: marqueeAnimation 4s linear infinite;
}

.marquee-content span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  /* Adjust as needed */
}

@keyframes marqueeAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(-100% + 100vw));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marquee-container">
  <div class="marquee-content">
    <span>All words and no speaking, makes us all write.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scroll distance needs to be:

- the distance from the left end of the original set to the left end of a duplicate set that starts out of view
- greater than the width of the view area

We also need enough elements to cover at least twice the width of view area.

Since we can't calculate the scroll distance in css, we use a css variable and have javascript fill it in.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    function calculateElements() {
        const containerWidth = $('.marquee-container').width();
        const elementWidth = $('.marquee-content span').outerWidth(true);
        const numElementsToFill = Math.ceil(containerWidth / elementWidth);
        const scrollDistance = elementWidth * numElementsToFill;
        $(':root').css('--marquee-scroll-width', `-${scrollDistance}px`);
        const numElementsToCreate = numElementsToFill * 2;
        for (let i = 1; i < numElementsToCreate; i++) {
            $('.marquee-content').append($('.marquee-content span:first').clone());
        }
    }

    calculateElements();
});
```

```css
:root {
  --marquee-scroll-width: 0px;
}
.marquee-container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
}

.marquee-content {
    display: flex;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    animation: marqueeAnimation 4s linear infinite;
}

.marquee-content span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

@keyframes marqueeAnimation {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(var(--marquee-scroll-width));
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marquee-container">
    <div class="marquee-content">
        <span>All words and no speaking, makes us all write.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Had no idea you could change the css variablen --marquee-scroll-width from JS. 
Tnak you so much :)